# Update content in AJAX render renderPartial

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Sory for my poor explanation, i hope this will be more clear:

In my action create in the model question i have this:

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model,'data'=>$data)); ?>

<div id="data">

</div>
```

Data will be the div that will be updated by ajax.

In the question's _form i have the dropdownList that will launch the ajax request:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Tipo de Pergunta <span class="required">*</span>'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'Tipo_Pergunta_idTipo_Pergunta', $this->getTipoPergunta(),
            array('prompt' => '-- Selecione tipo de pergunta --',
            'ajax' => array(
                    'type' => 'POST', 
                    'url' => CController::createUrl('Pergunta/UpdateAjax'),
                    'data'=> array('idTipo_Pergunta'=>'js: $(this).val()','id_Pergunta'=>1),  
                    'update'=>'#data',
                   )

            )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Tipo_Pergunta_idTipo_Pergunta'); ?>
</div>
```

In question controller i have the function updateAjax:

```
public function actionUpdateAjax()
{

    $selected = $_POST['idTipo_Pergunta'];      

    if($selected == 1)
    {       
        $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent',array('idquestion' => $idquestion), false, true);

    }           
}
```

Finally i have a php file in the view folder :

$this->renderPartial('/options/create',array('model'=>new options));

I have a model question and a model options. And at some point i want to render the form options inside the form question.

But, unfortunately didnt work, my fireBug shows :

CException

the property "options.Author_idUser" is not defined. (C:\wamp\www\sqquiz-med\framework\base\CComponent.php:130)

the property Author_idUser belongs to the model question :S

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you show a more complete snippet?  Some of your view file perhaps?

Comment: Agreed we need to see your the view file you are putting the `renderPartial` call in and the `options/create` view file.

Comment: Might also be helpful to see the controller action calling the original view.

Comment: Sory for my poor explanation, i hope this update the question will be more clear